# Hashchange to show divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hashchange

I have a number of divs on my page, which are hidden by default. Jobs can be selected by links (to "#job8,  for example). I'm trying to use hashchange in my script to check the URL for the specific hash and then to display the appropriate div.

This is an example div

```
<div class="job-details" id="job8" data-jobid="8">
    <p>Job 8</p>        
</div>
```

This is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.job-details').hide();
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

        if (location.hash.substring(0,4) == "#job"){
            var jobID = location.hash.substring(0);

            $('.job-details').hide();
            $('[data-jobid="' + jobID + '"]').show();
            }


});
```

Comment: Thank you Palpatim, Ishan Jain and Til. Changing the substring value to 4 in jobID works as it now matches the div's jobid data attribute. The selected div will now show, but only after the page has loaded, I need it to work as a permalink so that it can be saved or bookmarked.

 On a loaded page, adjusting the number changes the div. However, re-entering with the same number hides the div again. 

I've tried changing the hide() in hashchange to: 
`$('.job-details:not([data-jobid="' + jobID + '"]').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
var jobID = location.hash.substring(0);
```

Assigns '#' to `jobID`. Presumably that isn't what you want? Probably you want:

```
var jobID = location.hash.substring(4);
```

Comment: double-check your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you must use `hashchange`? If not try example below, here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/jTdy9/)**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#job1" data-rel="job1">Job 1</a>
  <a href="#job2" data-rel="job2">Job 2</a>
  <a href="#job3" data-rel="job3">Job 3</a>
</nav>

<div class="job-details" id="job1">
  <p>Job 1</p>        
</div>
<div class="job-details" id="job2">
  <p>Job 2</p>        
</div>
<div class="job-details" id="job3">
  <p>Job 3</p>        
</div>
```

---

```
.job-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('nav a').click(function() {
    $('.job-details').fadeOut(400);
    $('#'+$(this).data('rel')).fadeIn(400);
  });    
});
```

Comment: I did try click for the links, and also for close buttons, and that seemed to work. But I need to be able to bookmark the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Palpatim is right, this will do the job:

```
var jobID = location.hash.substring(4);
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cc9dL/

Comment: Thank you, yes it was just the number I needed for the jobID. The selected div shows now, but only after the page has loaded. I can adjust the number to change the div. However, re-entering with the same number the div hides itself again.

I've tried changing the hide() in hashchange to:
`$('.job-details:not([data-jobid="' + jobID + '"]').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery hashchange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/hashchange/)

Your function working correctly after making some changes in  get/set  `jobid`.

Here `location.hash` gives you `#job8`, so you can directly use this as `id` selector.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
     if (location.hash.substring(0,4) == "#job"){
         var jobID = location.hash;
         $('.job-details').hide();
         $(jobID).show();
     }
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTdy9/5/)

Updated :

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
     if (location.hash.substring(0,4) == "#job"){
        var jobID = location.hash.substring(4);
        $('.job-details').hide();
        $('div[data-jobid="' + jobID + '"]').show();
     }
});
```

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTdy9/7/)